# How to switch to browser window automatically after click?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

Whenever I click on a link in some app and it opens in the browser, I get a notification saying, "Google Chrome - $title is Ready" and the browser window stays in the background.

I can then click that notification to bring the browser window to the front.

Is there a way to automatically bring the window that was activated to the front without me having to click again?

Environment: Debian 12, GNOME 43.4, Chrome 114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the ***Focus my window*** Gnome shell extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1005/focus-my-window/

Its description is:

> Removes window is ready message and focuses the window instead

Answer (score 1):

I personally recommend this [NoAnnoyance v2](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/) extension.

Some of the other ones I've tried earlier had problems, e.g. some stopped working during longer sessions. This one has been working for me consistently for more than a year now.

It also has some settings like ignore list, if needed.